# Informix Stored Procedure and Java executeUpdate

Tags: java, stored-procedures, informix

Naturally I want to know how many rows have been affected when I call executeUpdate.
My executeUpdate calls a stored procedure that does the insert. I tried to return and int but I got "returns too many values" even tho it simply returns one int

I simply want to return the numbers of row affected

Java:

```
    String pro ="{call pro_insert(?,?,?)}";
     CallableStatement callableStatement =
     dbConn.prepareCall(pro);
     callableStatement.setString(1,"9600111");
     callableStatement.setInt(2,1);
     callableStatement.setInt(3,100);                       
     Integer id = callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Informix

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_insert ( source varchar(11), request_type_id smallint,result_code_id smallint  )
    RETURNING int ;

        INSERT INTO pro_table
        (
            source,request_type_id,result_code_id,time          
        )
        VALUES
        (
            source,request_type_id,result_code_id,CURRENT
        );

        return dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd2'); /* return number of rows affected */               
END PROCEDURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String pro ="{? = call pro_insert(?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement callableStatement = dbConn.prepareCall(pro);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.Integer);
callableStatement.setString(2,"9600111");
callableStatement.setInt(3,1);
callableStatement.setInt(4,100);                       
callableStatement.execute();
int res = callableStatement.getInt(1);
```